# elasticsearch.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'

Tags: elasticsearch

```
/$ sudo systemctl status elasticsearch
```

● elasticsearch.service - Elasticsearch
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/elasticsearch.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2021-10-26 06:35:35 UTC; 2min 23s ago
Docs: http://www.elastic.co
Process: 43447 ExecStart=/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch -p ${PID_DIR}/elasticsearch.pid --quiet (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Main PID: 43447 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Oct 26 06:35:35 ip-172-31-5-233 elasticsearch[43447]:         at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:161)
Oct 26 06:35:35 ip-172-31-5-233 elasticsearch[43447]:         at org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:86)
Oct 26 06:35:35 ip-172-31-5-233 elasticsearch[43447]:         at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:125)
Oct 26 06:35:35 ip-172-31-5-233 elasticsearch[43447]:         at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:90)
Oct 26 06:35:35 ip-172-31-5-233 elasticsearch[43447]:         at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:126)
Oct 26 06:35:35 ip-172-31-5-233 elasticsearch[43447]:         at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:92)
Oct 26 06:35:35 ip-172-31-5-233 elasticsearch[43447]: For complete error details, refer to the log at /var/log/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.log
Oct 26 06:35:35 ip-172-31-5-233 systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Oct 26 06:35:35 ip-172-31-5-233 systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Oct 26 06:35:35 ip-172-31-5-233 systemd[1]: Failed to start Elasticsearch.

> I previuosly had elasticsearch 7.15.1 installed. Uninstalled it and installed v 7.6.2, it shows this error from the first time I tried starting the service.

```
/$sudo cat var/log/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.log
```

[2021-10-26T06:40:17,473][INFO ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment    ] [ip-172-31-5-233] using [1] data paths, mounts [[/ (/dev/root)]], net usable_space [5.7gb], net total_space [19.3gb], types [ext4]
[2021-10-26T06:40:17,477][INFO ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment    ] [ip-172-31-5-233] heap size [1007.3mb], compressed ordinary object pointers [true]
[2021-10-26T06:40:17,614][ERROR][o.e.b.Bootstrap          ] [ip-172-31-5-233] Exception
org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException: failed to bind service
at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.(Node.java:615) ~[elasticsearch-7.6.2.jar:7.6.2]
at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.(Node.java:257) ~[elasticsearch-7.6.2.jar:7.6.2]
at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap$5.(Bootstrap.java:221) ~[elasticsearch-7.6.2.jar:7.6.2]
at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:221) ~[elasticsearch-7.6.2.jar:7.6.2]
at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:349) [elasticsearch-7.6.2.jar:7.6.2]
at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:170) [elasticsearch-7.6.2.jar:7.6.2]
at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:161) [elasticsearch-7.6.2.jar:7.6.2]
at org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:86) [elasticsearch-7.6.2.jar:7.6.2]
at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:125) [elasticsearch-cli-7.6.2.jar:7.6.2]
at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:90) [elasticsearch-cli-7.6.2.jar:7.6.2]
at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:126) [elasticsearch-7.6.2.jar:7.6.2]
at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:92) [elasticsearch-7.6.2.jar:7.6.2]
Caused by: org.apache.lucene.index.IndexFormatTooNewException: Format version is not supported (resource BufferedChecksumIndexInput(SimpleFSIndexInput(path="/var/lib/elasticsearch/nodes/0/_state/segments_2b"))): 10 (needs to be between 7 and 9)
at org.apache.lucene.codecs.CodecUtil.checkHeaderNoMagic(CodecUtil.java:216) ~[lucene-core-8.4.0.jar:8.4.0 bc02ab906445fcf4e297f4ef00ab4a54fdd72ca2 - jpountz - 2019-12-19 20:16:14]
at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos.readCommit(SegmentInfos.java:305) ~[lucene-core-8.4.0.jar:8.4.0 bc02ab906445fcf4e297f4ef00ab4a54fdd72ca2 - jpountz - 2019-12-19 20:16:14]
at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos.readCommit(SegmentInfos.java:289) ~[lucene-core-8.4.0.jar:8.4.0 bc02ab906445fcf4e297f4ef00ab4a54fdd72ca2 - jpountz - 2019-12-19 20:16:14]
at org.apache.lucene.index.StandardDirectoryReader$1.doBody(StandardDirectoryReader.java:64) ~[lucene-core-8.4.0.jar:8.4.0 bc02ab906445fcf4e297f4ef00ab4a54fdd72ca2 - jpountz - 2019-12-19 20:16:14]
at org.apache.lucene.index.StandardDirectoryReader$1.doBody(StandardDirectoryReader.java:61) ~[lucene-core-8.4.0.jar:8.4.0 bc02ab906445fcf4e297f4ef00ab4a54fdd72ca2 - jpountz - 2019-12-19 20:16:14]
at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos$FindSegmentsFile.run(SegmentInfos.java:680) ~[lucene-core-8.4.0.jar:8.4.0 bc02ab906445fcf4e297f4ef00ab4a54fdd72ca2 - jpountz - 2019-12-19 20:16:14]
at org.apache.lucene.index.StandardDirectoryReader.open(StandardDirectoryReader.java:84) ~[lucene-core-8.4.0.jar:8.4.0 bc02ab906445fcf4e297f4ef00ab4a54fdd72ca2 - jpountz - 2019-12-19 20:16:14]
at org.apache.lucene.index.DirectoryReader.open(DirectoryReader.java:76) ~[lucene-core-8.4.0.jar:8.4.0 bc02ab906445fcf4e297f4ef00ab4a54fdd72ca2 - jpountz - 2019-12-19 20:16:14]
at org.apache.lucene.index.DirectoryReader.open(DirectoryReader.java:64) ~[lucene-core-8.4.0.jar:8.4.0 bc02ab906445fcf4e297f4ef00ab4a54fdd72ca2 - jpountz - 2019-12-19 20:16:14]
at org.elasticsearch.gateway.PersistedClusterStateService.nodeMetaData(PersistedClusterStateService.java:262) ~[elasticsearch-7.6.2.jar:7.6.2]
at org.elasticsearch.env.NodeEnvironment.loadNodeMetaData(NodeEnvironment.java:408) ~[elasticsearch-7.6.2.jar:7.6.2]
at org.elasticsearch.env.NodeEnvironment.(NodeEnvironment.java:329) ~[elasticsearch-7.6.2.jar:7.6.2]
at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.(Node.java:277) ~[elasticsearch-7.6.2.jar:7.6.2]
... 11 more
[2021-10-26T06:40:17,623][ERROR][o.e.b.ElasticsearchUncaughtExceptionHandler] [ip-172-31-5-233] uncaught exception in thread [main]
org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.StartupException: ElasticsearchException[failed to bind service]; nested: IndexFormatTooNewException[Format version is not supported (resource BufferedChecksumIndexInput(SimpleFSIndexInput(path="/var/lib/elasticsearch/nodes/0/_state/segments_2b"))): 10 (needs to be between 7 and 9)];
at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:174) ~[elasticsearch-7.6.2.jar:7.6.2]
at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:161) ~[elasticsearch-7.6.2.jar:7.6.2]
at org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:86) ~[elasticsearch-7.6.2.jar:7.6.2]
at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:125) ~[elasticsearch-cli-7.6.2.jar:7.6.2]
at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:90) ~[elasticsearch-cli-7.6.2.jar:7.6.2]
at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:126) ~[elasticsearch-7.6.2.jar:7.6.2]
at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:92) ~[elasticsearch-7.6.2.jar:7.6.2]
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException: failed to bind service
at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.(Node.java:615) ~[elasticsearch-7.6.2.jar:7.6.2]
at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.(Node.java:257) ~[elasticsearch-7.6.2.jar:7.6.2]
at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap$5.(Bootstrap.java:221) ~[elasticsearch-7.6.2.jar:7.6.2]
at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:221) ~[elasticsearch-7.6.2.jar:7.6.2]
at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:349) ~[elasticsearch-7.6.2.jar:7.6.2]
at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:170) ~[elasticsearch-7.6.2.jar:7.6.2]
... 6 more
Caused by: org.apache.lucene.index.IndexFormatTooNewException: Format version is not supported (resource BufferedChecksumIndexInput(SimpleFSIndexInput(path="/var/lib/elasticsearch/nodes/0/_state/segments_2b"))): 10 (needs to be between 7 and 9)
at org.apache.lucene.codecs.CodecUtil.checkHeaderNoMagic(CodecUtil.java:216) ~[lucene-core-8.4.0.jar:8.4.0 bc02ab906445fcf4e297f4ef00ab4a54fdd72ca2 - jpountz - 2019-12-19 20:16:14]
at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos.readCommit(SegmentInfos.java:305) ~[lucene-core-8.4.0.jar:8.4.0 bc02ab906445fcf4e297f4ef00ab4a54fdd72ca2 - jpountz - 2019-12-19 20:16:14]
at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos.readCommit(SegmentInfos.java:289) ~[lucene-core-8.4.0.jar:8.4.0 bc02ab906445fcf4e297f4ef00ab4a54fdd72ca2 - jpountz - 2019-12-19 20:16:14]
at org.apache.lucene.index.StandardDirectoryReader$1.doBody(StandardDirectoryReader.java:64) ~[lucene-core-8.4.0.jar:8.4.0 bc02ab906445fcf4e297f4ef00ab4a54fdd72ca2 - jpountz - 2019-12-19 20:16:14]
at org.apache.lucene.index.StandardDirectoryReader$1.doBody(StandardDirectoryReader.java:61) ~[lucene-core-8.4.0.jar:8.4.0 bc02ab906445fcf4e297f4ef00ab4a54fdd72ca2 - jpountz - 2019-12-19 20:16:14]
at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos$FindSegmentsFile.run(SegmentInfos.java:680) ~[lucene-core-8.4.0.jar:8.4.0 bc02ab906445fcf4e297f4ef00ab4a54fdd72ca2 - jpountz - 2019-12-19 20:16:14]
at org.apache.lucene.index.StandardDirectoryReader.open(StandardDirectoryReader.java:84) ~[lucene-core-8.4.0.jar:8.4.0 bc02ab906445fcf4e297f4ef00ab4a54fdd72ca2 - jpountz - 2019-12-19 20:16:14]
at org.apache.lucene.index.DirectoryReader.open(DirectoryReader.java:76) ~[lucene-core-8.4.0.jar:8.4.0 bc02ab906445fcf4e297f4ef00ab4a54fdd72ca2 - jpountz - 2019-12-19 20:16:14]
at org.apache.lucene.index.DirectoryReader.open(DirectoryReader.java:64) ~[lucene-core-8.4.0.jar:8.4.0 bc02ab906445fcf4e297f4ef00ab4a54fdd72ca2 - jpountz - 2019-12-19 20:16:14]
at org.elasticsearch.gateway.PersistedClusterStateService.nodeMetaData(PersistedClusterStateService.java:262) ~[elasticsearch-7.6.2.jar:7.6.2]
at org.elasticsearch.env.NodeEnvironment.loadNodeMetaData(NodeEnvironment.java:408) ~[elasticsearch-7.6.2.jar:7.6.2]
at org.elasticsearch.env.NodeEnvironment.(NodeEnvironment.java:329) ~[elasticsearch-7.6.2.jar:7.6.2]
at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.(Node.java:277) ~[elasticsearch-7.6.2.jar:7.6.2]
at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.(Node.java:257) ~[elasticsearch-7.6.2.jar:7.6.2]
at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap$5.(Bootstrap.java:221) ~[elasticsearch-7.6.2.jar:7.6.2]
at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:221) ~[elasticsearch-7.6.2.jar:7.6.2]
at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:349) ~[elasticsearch-7.6.2.jar:7.6.2]
at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:170) ~[elasticsearch-7.6.2.jar:7.6.2]

Comment: You seem to have some left overs from the 7.15.1 installation `Format version is not supported`. make sure to really clean everything up before installing 7.6.2

Comment: you cannot downgrade like this, you need to do a full purge of everything including the data directory

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I managed to dockerize elasticsearch in a separate container with the required 7.6 version which seems to work fine.